# How can I define a new minted environment with optional arguments?

Tags: environments, minted, key-value, fancyvrb

I have the following mwe:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font=sf,labelfont=bf,skip=\smallskipamount}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {example} { mm  }
{\VerbatimEnvironment
 \captionof{lstlisting}{#2}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\label{#1}\fi%
\begin{minted}[linenos=true]{latex}}
{\end{minted}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {xexample} { o o  }
{\VerbatimEnvironment
  \IfNoValueF { #1 }%
    {\captionof{lstlisting}{#1}%
      \IfNoValueF {#2} { \label{#2} }%
   }%
  \begin{minted}[linenos=true]{latex}}%
 {\end{minted}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{TheLabel}{The caption}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption,floatrow}
\end{example}

%\begin{xexample}[Another caption]
%\usepackage{minted}
%\usepackage{caption,floatrow}
%\end{xexample}

See Example~\ref{TheLabel}

\end{document}
```

The environment `example` works like expected. However this environment has two mandatory arguments. I am a friend of optional arguments/keys. With the environment `xexample` I tried this implementation but it fails.

What's going on here?

Bonus: Is it possible to pass options to `minted` as well? (of course with an optional argument ;-))

Comment: why can't you use `\begin{minted}[caption=...,label=...]`??

Comment: @Herbert: `minted` doesn't provide the options `caption` nor `label`. egreg found a nice way: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9247614#9247614

Comment: it is pretty easy to make all options from  `fancyvrb` available for minted.

Comment: @Herbert: Do you mean `\fvset`? I have no idea?

Comment: the keys from `fancyvrb` are imported by `minted` with `\minted@define@extra{...}` Replace `...` with `label` and it is known. But I suppose that `fancyvrb` did not know the `caption` option.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that when verbatim-style environments take optional arguments, you need to use `\obeylines` to prevent the body of the environment from being tokenized in the process of checking for arguments.

You should be able to pass options to `minted`, though if you're primarily working with formatting, passing options directly to `\fvset` might be easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font=sf,labelfont=bf,skip=\smallskipamount}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {example} { mm  }
{\VerbatimEnvironment
 \captionof{lstlisting}{#2}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\label{#1}\fi%
\begin{minted}[linenos=true]{latex}}
{\end{minted}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {xexample} {}
{\VerbatimEnvironment
 \begingroup\obeylines\getargs}%
 {\end{minted}}

\NewDocumentCommand\getargs{ o o }
{\endgroup
  \IfNoValueF { #1 }%
    {\captionof{lstlisting}{#1}%
      \IfNoValueF {#2} { \label{#2} }%
   }%
  \begin{minted}[linenos=true]{latex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{TheLabel}{The caption}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption,floatrow}
\end{example}

\begin{xexample}[Another caption]
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption,floatrow}
\end{xexample}

See Example~\ref{TheLabel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting and a nice trick

Answer (score 7):

I propose a different syntax with a key-value interface that enables you to specify much more than the caption and the label, for instance options to be passed to `minted` and also the language.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font=sf,labelfont=bf,skip=\smallskipamount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {xexample}
 {
  caption  .tl_set:N = \l_mdxex_caption_tl,
  label    .tl_set:N = \l_mdxex_label_tl,
  minted   .tl_set:N = \l_mdxex_minted_tl,
  language .tl_set:N = \l_mdxex_language_tl
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment {xexample} { O {} }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { xexample }
   {
    language=latex,
    #1
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__mdxex_temp_tl
   {
    \exp_not:N \VerbatimEnvironment
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_mdxex_caption_tl
     {
      \scan_stop:
     }
     {
      \exp_not:N \captionof { lstlisting }{ \exp_not:V \l_mdxex_caption_tl }
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l_mdxex_label_tl
       { \exp_not:N \label { \l_mdxex_label_tl } }
     }
    \exp_not:n { \begin{minted} } [ \l_mdxex_minted_tl ] { \l_mdxex_language_tl }
   }
  \l__mdxex_temp_tl
 }
 {\end{minted}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{xexample}[caption=The caption,label=TheLabel,language=bash]
ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist
\end{xexample}

\begin{xexample}[caption=Another caption,label=foo,
  minted={linenos=true}]
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption,floatrow}
\end{xexample}

See example~\ref{TheLabel} and example~\ref{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to put the caption below the listings?

Comment: I like this approach, but it's giving me errors when no optional argument is supplied.

Comment: @G.Poore This should be fixed now.

Comment: @egreg Still throws an error for me if no optional arguments are provided: `FancyVerb Error: Extraneous input '\usepackage {minted}' between \begin{xexample}[<key=value>] and line end . \FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error: \space \space #1 }`