# minted Environment Inside varwidth Environment

Tags: minipage, minted, varwidth

Is there a way to incorporate a `minted` environment inside a `varwidth` environment? I have colored backgrounds for code snippets, and I did manage to put a `minted` environment inside a `minipage`, based on the answer to my previous question:

[minted Environment Inside minipage Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117077/minted-environment-inside-minipage-environment)

However, it is really frustrating to manually adjust the width of the minipage for each code snippet. I tried wrapping the `minted` environment with the `varwidth` environment in `minted.sty`, but am getting some weird errors.

Comment: `minted` uses `fancyvr` to print the material. Therefor the environment `Verbatim` is in used. Instead of this environment you can redefine some internals and use the environment `BVerbatim` which is also provided by `fancyvrb`

Comment: I'm kind of struggling a bit to edit the `minted.sty` file, since I'm still quite new to this. Could you perhaps help out a bit? Or maybe suggest an alternative, if jumping into the `minted` internals is just too cumbersome?

Comment: Getting errors with `varwidth` and a nested `minted` is not unexpected; but even if it worked, you'd not get anything more than with `minipage`, since `Verbatim` always uses the full text width available (as set by the document or by the `minipage` you're in).

Comment: Could you suggest any possible alternative?

Comment: @egreg: That's the reason for `BVerbatim` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point you can use the following redefinition. Maybe someone can improve my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted,varwidth}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mintedshort}[2][]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment%
  \renewcommand{\minted@proglang}[1]{#2}%
  \minted@resetoptions%
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{#1}%
  \begin{VerbatimOut}[codes={\catcode`\^^I=12}]{\jobname.pyg}}%
 {\end{VerbatimOut}%
  \minted@pygmentize@short{\minted@proglang{}}%
  \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}}

\newcommand\minted@pygmentize@short[2][\jobname.pyg]{%
  \def\minted@cmd{pygmentize -l #2 -f latex -F tokenmerge
    \minted@opt{gobble} \minted@opt{texcl} \minted@opt{mathescape}
    \minted@opt{startinline} \minted@opt{funcnamehighlighting}
    \minted@opt{linenos} -P "verboptions=\minted@opt{extra}"
    -o \jobname.out.pyg #1}%
  \immediate\write18{\minted@cmd}%
  \begingroup%
    \setbox0=\hbox{%
     \let\Verbatim\BVerbatim%
     \let\endVerbatim\endBVerbatim%
      \input{\jobname.out.pyg}%
    }%
   \box0%
   \endgroup%
  \DeleteFile{\jobname.out.pyg}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hrulefill
\begin{mintedshort}{latex}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\end{mintedshort}
\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Apparently, the options aren't working. I tried changing the background color, but it's not working. Moreover, using this environment inside a `varwidth` environment in my TeX file is still producing errors. I will try to embed the `varwidth` environment in `minted.sty`, based on your definition. This might take a while