# minted environment inside subcaptionbox is not working

Tags: subcaption, minted

I've seen some similar questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116627/package-minted-mint-command-not-working-inside-tabularx-environment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121117/minted-environment-inside-varwidth-environment), but none mention the `\subcaptionbox` command. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \subcaptionbox{One subfigure.}{%
            \begin{minted}{c}
                printf("hello, world\n");
            \end{minted}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile with a `Paragraph ended before \FV@BeginScanning was complete. }` error.

I could use a `minipage` environment and the `\subcaption` command instead, but `\subcaptionbox` has some advantages that I'd like to use.

Is there any way to make these two work together?

Comment: A verbatim environment cannot go in the argument to another command.

Comment: use the minted form that inputs a file and put your code fragments in external files so they are not contained in the argument of another command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried using `\subcaptionbox{One subfigure.}{\inputminted{c}{helloWorld.c}}` but still get errors: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a crude implementation, with just the standard form for `\subcaptionbox` (no optional arguments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{minted}

\newsavebox{\mintedbox}
\newenvironment{mintedsubcaptionbox}[2]
 {%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \def\mscbcaption{#1}%
  \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}%
  \begin{minted}{#2}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minted}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \subcaptionbox{\mscbcaption}{\usebox{\mintedbox}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]

\begin{mintedsubcaptionbox}{One subfigure.}{c}
printf("hello, world\n");
\end{mintedsubcaptionbox}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I used `BVerbatim` because it's quite unlikely that you want a listing to be full width inside a subfloat.

[image]

A fuller support with syntax

```
\begin{mintedsubcaptionbox}[<list entry>]{<heading>}[<minted options>]{<language>}
```

can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newsavebox{\mintedbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mintedsubcaptionbox}{O{#2}mO{}m}
 {%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}%
  \begin{minted}[#3]{#4}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minted}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \subcaptionbox[#1]{#2}{\usebox{\mintedbox}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]

\begin{mintedsubcaptionbox}{One subfigure.}{c}
printf("hello, world\n");
\end{mintedsubcaptionbox}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this solution too hacky to be included in the `minted` package out-of-the-box? Maybe I could suggest it.